# Check box inside drop down menu with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, checkbox

How can a checkbox inside a drop down menu using javascript to be implemented so that every time you click the menu to change situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website you have linked presents a list along this lines: http://jsfiddle.net/XJWkH/

Of course this is just a raw example but basically this is the way the dropdown list on the site works. When you click on a dropdown/submenu element, jQuery adds or removes 'checked' class on that element.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I have been looking for.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery is the easiest path here.  I have used [this plugin](http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/) with great success and have rolled my own as well.

Good luck!

Comment: I was talking for something like the 4th menu in this link: http://www.tavernoxoros.gr/